# Image upload preview using Amazon S3 with Keystone

Tags: mongodb, amazon-s3, content-management-system, keystonejs

I've searched for the last few hours and can't find an answer to this problem. When in the admin panel of keystone, is it possible to have a preview attached with the file you have uploaded? I have tried this below, but still nothing is showing up. I've noticed there is a class associated with Cloudinary Images Field and the image preview works if you are using cloundinary.

```
  format: function(item, file){
    return '<pre>'+JSON.stringify(file, false, 2)+'</pre>'+
                '<img src="'+file.url+'" style="max-width: 300px">'
}
```